# Evaluation of a function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $f(t)$ satisfies $\dfrac{d^2f(t)}{dt^2}-(2-3i)f(t)=0,\,f(0)=1,\,\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}f(t)=0$. What is $f(\pi)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $f'' = (2-3i)f$ is satisfied by $f(t) = C \sinh at + D\cosh at$ for both complex $a$ with $a^2 = 2-3i$ and for any constants $C$ and $D$. In particular, one such solution is

$$
    f(t) = \cosh at - \sinh at = e^{-ax},
$$
which satisfies $f(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ and also $f(0) = 1$. So one solution is $f(\pi)$.